# How can I get 2 `Panel` Objects to scroll simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, panel

I have 2 `Panel` objects on a form beside each other. 
When I scroll the 1st Panel I want the other to Scroll exactly the same amount.

Something like this.

```
private void Panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    Panel2.ScrollPosition() = Panel1.ScrollPosition();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with scottm, but adding something that makes a difference:

```
private void ScorePanel_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    var senderPanel = sender as Panel;

    if (senderPanel == null)
    {
        // Might want to print to debug or mbox something, because this shouldn't happen.
        return;
    }

    var otherPanel = senderPanel == Panel1 ? Panel2 : Panel1;

    otherPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = senderPanel.VerticalScroll.Value;
}
```

The other way, you would always update Panel1 to the scroll offset of Panel2, so if you scrolled Panel2, it would actually not scroll anything.

Now that you have this method, you should subscribe with both panels to it, like so:

```
Panel1.Scroll += ScorePanel_Scroll;
Panel2.Scroll += ScorePanel_Scroll;
```

This would probably be best done in the ctor of the form which contains the panels.

Comment: how do I subscribe both panels? sample code? thank you, much appreciated

Comment: @theIrishUser Added scroll event subscription example at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, this should work for you:

```
private void ScorePanel_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value;
}
```

[Reading MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) always helps in these situations.

Comment: Thanks scottm, 
Only thing is I scroll down just a little but and I get an out of range exception.
Although both panels have the same data objects them

Comment: @theIrishUser, are the panels the same size? You might need to add a little validation to check that the current value is > 0 within the range of the second panel

Comment: they are the same size, I solved the problem by setting the max size through code when they were initialised. Now my problem is they don't always stay in sync. (If I move the mouse fast)